# Как в список вставить ссылку (wp_nav_menu)?

Tags: php, wordpress

Вывод меню происходит вот так

```
        <?php 
            $defaults = array(
                'menu' => 'TopMenu',
                'container' => 'div',
                'container_id' => 'nav',);
                echo wp_nav_menu($defaults);
        ?>
```

Как сюда в список вставить ссылку Главная? Не в админке! Там то все ясно. Мне просто нужно вместо текста Главная воткнуть изображение.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Такой трюк можно провернуть и не углубляясь в программирование и изучение `Walker_Nav_Menu`.

Необходимо в админке, находясь на странице **Внешний вид** - **Меню** вызвать вверху экрана **Настройки экрана** и в блоке **Показывать расширенные свойства меню** установить галочку **Классы CSS**.

Теперь появится возможность любому пункту меню задать индивидуальный класс. Что и необходимо сделать в элементе Главной страницы.

Дальше дело за малым - при помощи стилей установить для заданного класса нужный `background` (картинку), размеры и т.д., а также спрятать название пункта меню (примеры замещения текста картинкой в сети найти не проблема).

Answer (score 1):

Пошарил в инете, сам с `wordpress` не работал.
Идея такова что вывод нужно сделать вот так:

```
<?php 
$walker=new myMenuWalker();
            $defaults = array(
                'menu' => 'TopMenu',
                'container' => 'div',
                'container_id' => 'nav',
                'walker' => $walker);
                echo wp_nav_menu($defaults);
        ?>
```

где `myMenuWalker` - класс расширяющий существующий класс построителяч меню `Walker_Nav_Menu`.

вот [тут](http://belbiy.com/bg/wp_nav_menu-and-custom-walker-class/) написано как можно расширить класс и пример есть